# Saving a notebook as PDF not working

Tags: front-end, export, pdf-format, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to save the notebook as PDF with working. I tried all methods in old threads but nothing works.
Does anyone know how to make this work?
(version 12.0.0.0, windows 64-bit)

```
SetOptions[
  SelectedNotebook[], 
  PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Printout", ShowSyntaxStyles -> True]
f[a_, b_, d_] := (a + b)/(a - b) d;
tup1 = Tuples@{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0, 3}};
Quiet@Check[
       t = Plot[{f[##, d], 1}, {d, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 1000, 
         PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["a= `` b= ``", ##]]]; t, 
       Nothing[]] & @@@ tup1 // Flatten // 
  Partition[#, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}] & // Grid
```

Also how to print PDF a whole notebook with many inputs and outputs not just graphics?

Comment: Why not use `Export["test.pdf",%]` ?

Comment: @cvgmt I didn't know that this work. It somehow works but there is a problem with margin. Where can I set the margin?

Comment: Also how can I use that command for the whole notebook with many outputs and inputs?

Comment: I know nothing about Windows, but on MacOS, to save a notebook in a PDF file, I click on Print in the File menu and then choose save as PDF in the print dialog that appears. Maybe something similar works on Windows?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work well. The graphic is cut off a lot.

Comment: @anhnha I’ve printed several pdfs of notebooks for class & unfortunately all I found to work was to just organize the notebook rather carefully. You can change the way your notebook is displayed as you work on it & I found that to be a bit helpful.

Comment: Is that the only option? Too bad actually

Comment: I tried `Export` to export the whole notebook as working but it didn't work.

Comment: “Nothing works” to me means no file is produced. “Doesn’t work well” means something else. Please clarify.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I can export the file but the graphics are cut off  not like the working view.

Answer (score 3):

In V12.0, I get graphics to be broken across pages if I set their `ImageSize` to be wider than the page width, even though `PageBreakWithin` is set to `False`.  For instance, it happens with `ImageSize -> 1000` for me, which setting is the same as in the OP.

Try  `ImageSize -> Full` if you want the graphics as wide as the page.

[In V12.1/12.2, the graphics are not broken at page breaks.]

Comment: I just updated to 12.2 but the problem still remains.

Comment: @anhnha Does `ImageSize -> Full` solve the problem for you?

Comment: you're right. That works. What is the reason? I still have overlapping labels problem with long label

Comment: @anhnha I don't know.  If the other behavior is a bug, then the explanation is that `Full` simply works correctly.

Comment: I tried another notebook and got labels overlapping of two graphs horizontally

Answer (score 1):

On an Apple, simply printing to a file works.

Why not print to a file, and then see what your print settings are set at?

Can you print to a printer?

**UPDATE (see comments below)**

Please try updating to *Mathematica* Version 12.1 or 12.2.

Comment: It does not work for me on a Mac in V12.0 or in V12.2, if I set `ImageSize -> 1000`.

Comment: Does a notebook's size have something to do with `ImageSize`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to. But I made a mistake in my first comment.  In V12.2 the graphics are just cut off at the right margin, but the entire height of each appears on one page.  In V12.0, the graphics are broken at page breaks, too. I must have gotten confused which version I was running. :)

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure what the issue is.  Running 12.1.1.0 on a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.14.6, and trying out the OP's code, and printing to a file.  Seems to work as expected.

Comment: Maybe it was a bug in 12.0.

Comment: Sounds like it.

Comment: Is there a new version? If so then I should update.

Comment: Looks like 12.2 is the latest.  https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html

Comment: I did use print before. Virtual printer to print PDF but it didn't work. 
now just updated to 12.2 but still couldn't solve it

Comment: Can you print to a printer?

Comment: I did but the result is same as PDF.

Comment: Is it Mathematica, or your general printing set up?  Perhaps somebody with Windows can comment.  Are others able to print?  What settings work?

Comment: my printer setting works file for printing PDF. I don't know what happened with Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

We have two questions: 1) How to make a PDF from a grid of graphics (output of `Plot`), and 2) How to make a PDF for a whole notebook.

For the second question... Here's a way to make a PDF of a whole notebook including inputs and outputs. [`NotebookPrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookPrint.html) saves a print-ready form of a notebook to a file in the format indicated by a file extension. First, open a notebook as a `NotebookObject` with [`NotebookOpen`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookOpen.html), then use the *file.ext* option of `NotebookPrint` to make a PDF file. For example:

```
file = FileNameJoin[{$WolframDocumentsDirectory, "notebook.nb"}];
nb = NotebookOpen[file];
NotebookPrint[nb, "notebook.pdf"];
```

For the grid of graphics, use [`CreateDocument`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDocument.html) to make a new notebook from an expression or expressions. Using the example from your question:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{f[a_, b_, d_] := (a + b)/(a - b) d;
    tup1 = Tuples@{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0, 3}};
    Quiet@
          Check[t = 
            Plot[{f[##, d], 1}, {d, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 1000, 
             PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["a= `` b= ``", ##]]]; t, 
           Nothing[]] & @@@ tup1 // Flatten // 
      Partition[#, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}] & // Grid}];

NotebookPrint[nb, "plots.pdf"];
```

I tried several detailed notebooks with mixed graphics, inputs and outputs. `NotebookPrint` created PDFs that scaled large graphics to a single page (graphics are not split at page breaks, although I found a large, rasterized image that worked better with smaller dimensions). Inputs and outputs are formatted to closely match the notebook appearance.

Comment: I tried your code but the print doesn't look like working view where I have 2 graphics horizontally.
https://ibb.co/56r1FCH

Comment: @anhnha I don't have a notebook that shows that issue. Maybe it's similar to the problem I found with the large rasterized image. If you have a specific example, please edit your question, however, I suggest that problem might be a topic for a new question.

Comment: specific example? I just copied your code above 100% to save as PDF.

Comment: my question is about saving it with screen environment as working so it should include  two horizontally-aligned graphics as the working shows that?